# How to sync data between from a SQL DB in Azure SQL Server to another SQL DB in a different Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I would like to create a single directional sync transaction between the DBs.

For Example:

Azure SQL Server 1 has DB1

Azure SQL Server 2 has DB2

I would like the changes from DB1 to be synced to DB2. But, if I create
additional tables on DB2, it should not affect DB1.

I am trying to avoid Data Factory Sync, unless its the only way.

Comment: Azure SQL DB or Managed Instance? MI can be a replication publisher while Azure SQL only a subscriber. There's [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql-db) for Azure SQL DB. The [Data replication on Azure SQL Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-sql-replication/) also covers Change Tracking, CDC  which requires some manual coding to apply changes to the target database

Comment: "sync data" is one of those very short phrases in a project plan which inevitably turns into a year-long project where half the team has to confront the CAP theorem, while the other half slack-off because they know the project is doomed.

Comment: Actually, its been two years... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql) in that scenario. You can have replication on one direction or bidirectional. You can schedule the replication with a frequency of seconds, minutes, hours, days, manually. With SQL Data Sync you can add more tables to the destination database without any problem but you cannot change the schema of tables participating on a sync group without having to reconfigure the sync.

A sync group is a logical grouping of SQL Database instances and optional SQL Server databases. This grouping defines which databases, tables and columns are synchronized together. You can have many sync groups defined.

Comment: The documentation for Azure SQL Data Sync says "_Data Sync uses insert, update, and delete triggers to track change_" - that basically means you can't use the `OUTPUT` clause of DML anymore - that's potentially a huge deal-killer for databases making heavy use of `MERGE` - do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: Since the tool was introduced back in 2012, I have not read anybody complaining about that on Stackoverflow, on MSDN forums or on Microsoft QA forums. It is not a documented limitation also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql#general-limitations

Comment: @Dai, it's only OUTPUT to the éther, that doesn't work, OUTPUT INTO table still works with triggers if i remember correctly.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks to both.